# Multiple ID In Javascript Function Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, multiple-instances

I am trying to toggle the password on two fields with different ids using one JavaScript code but it isn't working.

One field works fine but the other doesn't respond, I have tried different solutions but I am not getting it right.

Any help will be appreciated.

**See code below;**

```js
const togglePassword = document.querySelectorAll("#togglePassword, #togglePassword23");
        const password = document.querySelectorAll("#input2, #signup3");
        

        togglePassword.addEventListener("click", function toggle() {
            // toggle the type attribute
const type = password.getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
            password.setAttribute("type", type);
            
            // toggle the icon
            this.classList.toggle("bi-eye");
        });
```

```html
<input type="password" id="input2" autocomplete="new-password"><br/>
<input id="togglePassword" type="button" value="Toggle password 1" onclick="toggle();">
      <br/> <br/>
      
<input type="password" id="signup3" autocomplete="new-password"><br/>
<input id="togglePassword23" type="button" value="Toggle password 2" onclick="toggle();">
```

Comment: Ids must be unique on a page. You have two the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working version of somewhat what you are trying to do. Should at least give you an idea of what was wrong with what you were trying:

```js
const togglePassword = document.querySelectorAll("#togglePassword1, #togglePassword2");
const password = document.querySelectorAll("#input2, #input3");
        
togglePassword.forEach(function(item, index){
  item.addEventListener("click", function toggle() {
      // toggle the type attribute
      const type = password[index].getAttribute("type") === "password" ? "text" : "password";
      password[index].setAttribute("type", type);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="password" id="input2" autocomplete="new-password"><br/>
<input id="togglePassword1" type="button" value="Toggle password 1" >
<br/> <br/>
<input type="password" id="input3" autocomplete="new-password"><br/>
<input id="togglePassword2" type="button" value="Toggle password 2" >
```

Comment: Thanks Laslos, You rock!

Answer (score 1):

You can find more details in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). In a nutshell - it returns an element object representing **the first element** in the document that **matches the specified set of CSS selectors**, or null is returned if there are no matches.

If you need a list of all elements matching the specified selectors, you should use `querySelectorAll()` instead.

p.s. Also, there is a typo in this line (I guess):

```
const password = document.querySelector("#input2, #input2"); // input2 input2 ???
```

Comment: I have edited my question with the solutions suggested by you, Andy, and ikos23 and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @BABOSAMMONG now your question is a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54937271/why-do-i-get-undefined-when-i-change-from-queryselector-to-queryselectorall